# What is in c:\winnt\softwaredistribution\scanfile?

Tags: windows-2000

Running a couple of Windows 2000 boxes, and the above folder keeps being populated with sub folders named like a SID.

What is being generated here, and is there a way to stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SoftwareDistribution` is the Windows Update folder. You can delete it (with the Update Service disabled), but it'll just come back again.

Comment: Even though Windows Updates are disabled and they don't have network access?  It seems to be generating the same 20MB worth of files every day.

Comment: If the Automatic Updates or BITS services are running, it'll carry on creating files. WSUS or MBSA can also write to that folder.